flutter build failure with problem occurred configuring project
i'm building a flutter app where i'm using better_player plugin, the app was running just fine until it started giving me this error when i run it:
Launching lib/main.dart on SM N950F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':better_player'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

     If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 14s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

this is my android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

this is app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.seriez"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.seriez"
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}


and settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

include ":app"


and pubspec.yaml
name: seriez
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.0 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.4.1
  flutter_carousel_widget: ^2.3.0
  provider: ^6.1.2
  flutter_typeahead: ^5.2.0
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  flutter_blurhash: ^0.8.2
  video_player: ^2.9.2
  sembast: ^3.7.4
  path_provider: ^2.1.4
  dio: ^5.7.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.2
  http: ^1.2.2
  wakelock_plus: ^1.2.8
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.11
  sizer: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.3.1
  better_player: ^0.0.84
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/data/


thanks in advance

What is the API level of SM N950F? Also, what is the compile/target sdk level you are targeting? Are you sure the issue stems from better_player?

@tomerpacific, I just solved the problem, thank you so much.

check this out and let me know how it goes

@yormen, yeah that was the solution as I mentioned in my answer. Thanks a million.

I managed to solve the issue by adding the namespace to the android section in the plugin's android/build.gradle, then i got the error
Launching lib/main.dart on SM N950F in debug mode...
 2 ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.


so, i set
compileSdk = 34
minSdk = 24
targetSdk = 33
and all errors were gone and my App ran normally
